# iOS provisioning still won't work - keys and cer. not connected?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, xcode4.3

After reading countless guides, tutorials and intros, I still can't get my app onto my device.  I have 2 keys (actually more like 20 because of my many attempts), and 4 certificates, but the certificates and keys are not hooked up like they should be. I guess I didn't hook it up right in the provisioning tutorial launcher on the Apple dev site. How can I do it manually? I have done every possible combination, using every tool at my disposal, and it just isn't working. Every time I try to install the cer., which is supposed to allow me to connect it to a key, it  just opens up the login key. This is contrary to every tutorial I have seen yet, which says double-clicking the file will let you install it. I'm sure I just keep making some little mistake along the way, but if you can help me out I would be so thankful!

Comment: I feel your pain, brother developer. The process is difficult and opaque. I have a theory that Apple intentionally makes it painful to weed out all but the most determined and resourceful, so as to raise the average quality of apps. </rant>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GOTO your xcode organizer and try refresh.(See bottom right button in provisioning profile section)[image]

[image]

Comment: To expand on Raj's answer a bit.  Originally, had to do a lot of this process yourself.  Apple has since put a lot of this functionality into Xcode, so the download and install of certificates and profiles is now automated.
Also check Apple's TN2050

Comment: @Gordon Dove, thx for the info, please send link for Apple's TN2050.

Comment: Ok I'm going to go through the process again. Thanks guys. Unfortunately the day I decided to do this was the day Apple's development site was down.....